# Why java doesn't give me compile error when I use public functions of one class in another class explicitly

Tags: java

I have two classes class1, and class1Test, in two different files, and two different folders. The first one is in folder src, and the second one in folder test (same project). Now imagine I have this code in my class1Test and function1ofClass1 is public:

```
class1 c1 = new class1();
    int a = function1ofClass1();
    int b = c1.function1ofClass1();
```

Obviously the first call of function1ofClass1 is not correct, but in this situation, why java (I am using eclipse) doesn't give me a compile error? I know that C# would. Am I doing something wrong with my filing organization or this is the way java works?

Comment: Does the test class extend the other class? In that case it would be inheriting function1ofClass1 and would therefore compile.

Comment: Can you give a _complete_ example. Definition of `Class1` and class that contains this code sample is not clear.

Comment: @andersschuller Only if the method is at least `protected`.

Comment: @m0skit0 The question says "function1ofClass1 is public". And it must be, otherwise `c1.function1ofClass1()` would not compile either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seem your test class extends the class containing that function that's why the compiler does not give you compile error.

Comment: I created the test class using wizard in eclipse and it added the extends itself. I omitted that extends and still works fine, I am not sure why it did that automatically. It seems not needed.

Answer (score 0):

> The first one is in folder src, and the second one in folder test

And you are using an IDE which has set this up for you. It has added `src/java` and `test/java` to your classpath: as such, classes `class1` (in, say, `src/java/foo/bar`) and `class1Test` (in `test/java/foo/bar`) are in the same namespace.

It is therefore normal.

Answer (score 0):

Is `function1ofClass1` declared as `static`? In that case both calls are perfectly valid, provided the function has been imported (which your IDE may have done for you).